# Get child group members with Get-QADGroupMember

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to get all Members of a group testgroup1, but inside this group are other groups testgroup2, testgroup3.

The output of `Get-QADGroupMember "testgroup1"` is a list of members inside `testgroup1` but it lists all the other groups inside like Members.

Example for a line where it should work:

```
$adgroup = Get-QADGroup
$adgroup | where {$_.Name -like "testgroup1"} | Get-QADGroupMember -Enabled
```

If I add `-Indirect` it also displays the group, but I only want to show the users:

```
$adgroup = Get-QADGroup
$adgroup | where {$_.Name -like "testgroup1"} | Get-QADGroupMember -Enabled -Indirect
```

How can I get all members of the `testgroup1` and all the members of the groups that are inside it with `Get-QADGroupMember`?

Comment: If I got you right you simply need to use the parameter `-Recursive` for the cmdlet `Get-ADGroupMember`.

Comment: @Olaf - For some reason, he's insisting on using the QUEST AD module instead of Microsoft's.

Comment: Yeah i have to use Quest AD because the whole script is build with QAD so i can't use Microsoft's AD module

Comment: @JeffZeitlin ...  ah ... ok ... thanks. So I'm out then.  ;-)

Comment: @Uni_x  ... hmmm ... maybe a really good reason to rewrite it?  ... with a more modern approach  ...

Comment: It probably _should_ be rewritten; I don't believe that the Quest cmdlets are still supported; IIRC, Quest was borged by Dell.

Comment: Well i am only an apprentice on the beginning of my career.My Job was to edit the script. My next aim is to rewrite it with modern methods like microsofts AD Module. QAD is very slow...

Comment: You'll probably find that a workable "first cut" at this will often replace the Quest "QAD" cmdlet with the Microsoft cmdlet that carries the same name without the "Q" - but do a `Get-Help «cmdletname» -Full` on both the Quest and Microsoft cmdlets first, so that you can become aware of any differences between them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you appear to be insisting on using `Get-QADGroupMember` instead of Microsoft's own `Get-ADGroupMember`, you might find [this WikiDot page](http://spundae.wikidot.com/get-qadgroupmember) of interest; it implies that what you want is the `-Indirect` parameter, which appears to do the same thing as the `-Recursive` of Microsoft's `Get-ADGroupMember`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-QADGroupMember testgroup1 -Indirect | select samaccountname
```

Comment: A bit explanation around your example would help the OP and others coming here later.